# How to revert base ftp dir to my user home dir?

Tags: linux, ftp

When I connect to my linux server via FTP, my base folder upon login is not my user home directory, but instead '/www'.

'/www' belongs to user root and one of the secondary groups for my user account.

I am connecting via SFTP, using my username/password, and without setting any default root directories.  I get the same behavior in multiple clients (Dreamweaver/Cyberduck), both active/passive connect modes.

Does anyone have any idea how to correct this strange behavior?

Comment: Do you have admin access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it editing your /etc/passwd file changing the home directory. Eg. username:x:527:527::/home/username:/bin/bash

Comment: Will I need to restart the machine?  Or just the FTP server? .....Also, what is the significance of the numbers (527:527)? The numbers next to my username in /etc/passwd is different.

Comment: You must preserv your number, it´s your account ID. restart is not requeired because ftp will check home path each new login. The passwd file sintax is:
The field descriptions are:
account:password:UID:GID:GECOS:HOME directory:shell